# Spring boot in combination with Java 22?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am currently trying to update my Spring boot and Vaadin project to Java 22.

Maybe it's just me but I can't seem to find out if Spring boot is already compatible with Java 22, and if so, on which version? I would've expected it to have it supported from the release. I hope there is an actual release and not some snapshot version? :)

Comment: This states that 3.2.4 supports Java 22: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html#getting-started.system-requirements

Comment: @GenerousBadger it seems that I was too early today in my search... As now I posted this at the end of my day to hope to have someone reply before I start again tomorrow, but the post was up 3 hours ago :) They said it's on maven central but I only see it up to 3.2.3 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot :( But I guess by the time I start work again tomorrow it should be there :) Thanks!

If you post the reply as an answer I'll mark it as the correct answer :)

Comment: I see 3.2.4 on Maven Central: https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/overview